# Avoid my images (which are links) to have a bottom border

Tags: html, css

I defined a bottom border (2px) on my anchor links.

**The problem:** this bottom border is also applied on my image when these are links.

How to avoid this bottom border on images?

Html:

```
<a href="#">hello</a>
<a href="#">
    <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cosmo-medicine/40/dog-128.png">
</a>
```

Css:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #3e3e3e;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #60bbd2;
}

a img {
    border: 0;
}

a:hover{
    border-bottom: 0px none;
    color: #60bbd2;
}
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8L63n7nu/1/

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The border is not on the `img`, it's on the `a`, which is why `a img {border: 0;}` changes nothing. CSS unfortunetly doesn't have a :parent or :contains-selector which you could use to check if the `a` contains an image, so you'll have to separate links that do somehow. I suggest giving the links a class, for instance like this:

```
<a href="#" class="image">
    <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cosmo-medicine/40/dog-128.png">
</a>
```

And add rule:

```
a.image{border:none}
```

...or...

If you don't want to add classes, you'll have to use JS. jQuery has got the `:has()` selector, which you can use to check if the element contains specified elements. If you wrap this in a jQuery wrapper, it's run when the page loads and works just like css would.

```
$(function(){
    $("a:has(img)").css({border:"none"});
});
```

Be aware, that if you add more links without refreshing the page - for instance with ajax - you'll have to run the above function again to process the new links.

Here's also a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8L63n7nu/20/).

Comment: That's not JS. It's jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to the anchors with the image in them

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="img">
    <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cosmo-medicine/40/dog-128.png">
</a>
```

CSS:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #3e3e3e;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #60bbd2;
}

a.img {
    border: 0;
}

a:hover{
    border-bottom: 0px none;
    color: #60bbd2;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8L63n7nu/14/

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot add any classes I don't have access to html code.

Comment: What about JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: Javascript / jQuery may ba acceptable but I tought it may be possible with css only

Comment: Unfortunately you can't go up in CSS. Check out Ilpo Oksanen's JS approach

Comment: @Demnogonis Not true. Please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30594201/1234256).

Comment: @Mooseman: You're applying a negative margin to the image to mask the border created by the `<a>`. What I meant by "going up" in CSS was a [parent selector](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1014861/912500), which is not yet supported in CSS [(CSS4 draft)](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/). However your approach works as long as the `<a>` tag doesn't get a padding from somewhere.